# Adding new items count from Model

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a model as such:

- Company

  - Department

    - Person (Name, Nationality, New)
    - Person (Name, Nationality, New)
    - Person (Name, Nationality, New)
    - Person (Name, Nationality, New)
  - Department

    - Person (Name, Nationality, New)
    - Person (Name, Nationality, New)
  - Department

    - Person (Name, Nationality, New)
    - Person (Name, Nationality, New)
    - Person (Name, Nationality, New)

The person's "New" property is a bool. How can I have a dynamic count of the number of new employees in each department on my UI for the company?

I have set up a TextBox in my XAML of my MainView for each company and I would like that textbox to tell me the total number of new people in the company (from all of the departments). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to have a dedicated department view and view model. The department view model would then expose all the `Person` instances as well as a `NewPersonCount` property reflecting the value that you want.

Here is a crude example of the new view model (omitting the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and all):

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Person> People {get; set; }
  public int NewPeopleCount
  {
    get
    {
      return People.Where(p => p.New).Count();
    }
  }
}
```

A department view would bind to it (for instance, `NewPeopleCount` to be shown in `TextBox`). Your main view would most likely have a `ListView` or some other `ItemsControl` bind to all the departments, showing the department views.

Comment: Could you give a few more details on hwo to implement it?

Comment: Adjusted my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the required data structures and creates properties that would return the required value

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string Nationality;
    public bool New;
}

public class Department
{
    public List<Person> EmployeeList;
    public void Add(Person person)
    {
        if (EmployeeList == null)
            EmployeeList = new List<Person>();
        EmployeeList.Add(person);

    }
    public int GetNewPersonCount
    {
        get
        {
            int count = 0;
            if (EmployeeList != null)
            {
                foreach (Person p in EmployeeList)
                {
                    if (p.New)
                        count++;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public List<Department> DepartmentList;
    public void Add(Department department)
    {
        if (DepartmentList == null)
            DepartmentList = new List<Department>();
        DepartmentList.Add(department);


    }
    public int GetNewPersonCount
    {
        get
        {
            int count = 0;
            if (DepartmentList != null)
            {
                foreach (Department d in DepartmentList)
                {
                    count += d.GetNewPersonCount;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```